# dplyr: Calculate percent change between summarized groups

Tags: r, dplyr, percentage

I am trying to calculate percentage change between groups, with one control ands several treatments, organized as groups in my data.frame. As I have many observations, I am using `dplyr`. What I do not understand, is how to effectively set which group to compare to? Normally, I would split this task in multiple steps:

- calculate means by groups
- subset control group to create a new 'control' dataframe
- join 'control' dataframe to first df
- Calculate % change between control and treatments.

I wonder, however, if `dplyr` does not have a simpler a straightforward way already?

Dummy example

```
set.seed(5)
dd <- data.frame(id = rep(c(1:4), 3),
                 val = c(rnorm(4) +2,
                         rnorm(4) +3,
                         rnorm(4) +4),
                 grp = rep(c("control", "ch1", "ch2"), each = 4))

dd %>% 
  group_by(grp) %>% 
  summarise(my_mean = mean(val))
```

Expected outcome with calculated % change between 'control' and individual treatments:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  grp     my_mean   perc_change
  <fct>     <dbl>
1 ch1        2.30    XX
2 ch2        5.00    YY
3 control    1.39    0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you want this?

```r
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(5)
dd <- data.frame(id = rep(c(1:4), 3),
                 val = c(rnorm(4) +2,
                         rnorm(4) +3,
                         rnorm(4) +4),
                 grp = rep(c("control", "ch1", "ch2"), each = 4))

dd %>% 
  group_by(grp) %>% 
  summarise(my_mean = mean(val)) %>%
  mutate(perc_change = scales::percent((my_mean - my_mean[grp == 'control'])/my_mean[grp == 'control']))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>   grp     my_mean perc_change
#>   <chr>     <dbl> <chr>      
#> 1 ch1        3.00 63%        
#> 2 ch2        4.07 121%       
#> 3 control    1.84 0%
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much!! That's looks great! please, how to set it to calculate values as numeric, not as characters? (eg. exclude % sign from the row values)?

Comment: Cool, got it! just easy like this `mutate(perc_change = (my_mean - my_mean[grp == 'control'])/my_mean[grp == 'control']*100)`, or maybe even something simpler?

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for this?

```
library(dplyr)

dd %>% 
  group_by(grp) %>% 
  summarise(my_mean = mean(val))  %>%
  mutate(perc_change = (my_mean - my_mean[match('control', grp)])/ my_mean[match('control', grp)] * 100)
  #Also we can use '=='
  #mutate(perc_change = (my_mean - my_mean[grp == 'control'])/ my_mean[grp == 'control'] * 100)
```