# dplyr: calculate % change between multiple groups?

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to calculate percent change between different groups, where I am using several grouping variables. Comparing to question answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68601082/dplyr-calculate-percent-change-between-summarized-groups/68601123#68601123), I have several columns to which I wish to find a % change. Within the 'control' and change groups, I also have a variants `a` and `b`. So I wish to have my change in treatments `ch1` and `ch2` relative to variant `a` and `b` in `control` group.

However, I am not sure how to correctly indicate this in the `dplyr` format?

Dummy example:

```
set.seed(5)
dd <- data.frame(id = rep(c(1:4), 3),
                 val = c(rnorm(4) +2,
                         rnorm(4) +3,
                         rnorm(4) +4),
                 grp = rep(c("control", "ch1", "ch2"), each = 4),
                 gr2 = rep(c("a", "b")))


dd %>% 
  group_by(grp, gr2) %>%   # summarize by multiple groups
  summarise(my_mean = mean(val)) %>%
  mutate(perc_change = (my_mean - my_mean[grp == 'control'& gr2 == 'a'])/my_mean[grp == 'control' & gr2 == 'a']*100) # !! how to set this line correcty?
```

Expected outcome:

```
  grp     gr2   my_mean   perc_change
  <fct>   <fct>   <dbl>
1 ch1     a       3.62    ..
2 ch1     b       2.38    ..
3 ch2     a       4.47    ..
4 ch2     b       3.67    ..
5 control a       0.952   0
6 control b       2.73    0
```

Comment: Please, where do you mean, @akrun?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to do it with some simple bracket selections (using `[ ]`) inside of `mutate`. No extra joins needed!

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(5)
dd <- data.frame(id = rep(c(1:4), 3),
                 val = c(rnorm(4) +2,
                         rnorm(4) +3,
                         rnorm(4) +4),
                 grp = rep(c("control", "ch1", "ch2"), each = 4),
                 gr2 = rep(c("a", "b")))

out <- dd %>% 
  group_by(grp, gr2) %>% 
  summarize(
    my_mean = mean(val)
  ) %>% 
  group_by(gr2) %>% 
  mutate(
    perc_change = my_mean / my_mean[grp == 'control'] - 1
  )

  grp     gr2   my_mean perc_change
  <chr>   <chr>   <dbl>       <dbl>
1 ch1     a       3.62        2.80 
2 ch1     b       2.38       -0.127
3 ch2     a       4.47        3.70 
4 ch2     b       3.67        0.345
5 control a       0.952       0    
6 control b       2.73        0
```

Comment: I like this solution a lot! please, could you explained why you use `-1` in `my_mean / my_mean[grp == 'control'] - 1`? I need to adjust this solution to my larger dataset, and I wish to avoid that it makes lag between rows or something similar. thanks again!

Comment: New / Old - 1 = (New - Old) / Old. Both are the formula for simple percentage change.

Answer (score 2):

Not a very sophisticated way, but you could use

```r
df <- dd %>% 
  group_by(grp, gr2) %>%   # summarize by multiple groups
  summarise(my_mean = mean(val), .groups = "keep")


df %>%
  left_join(filter(df, grp == "control"), by = "gr2") %>% 
  mutate(perc_change = (my_mean.x - my_mean.y) / my_mean.y) %>% 
  select(grp = grp.x, gr2, my_mean = my_mean.x, perc_change) %>%
  ungroup()
```

which returns

```r
# A tibble: 6 x 4
  grp     gr2   my_mean perc_change
  <chr>   <chr>   <dbl>       <dbl>
1 ch1     a       3.62        2.80 
2 ch1     b       2.38       -0.127
3 ch2     a       4.47        3.70 
4 ch2     b       3.67        0.345
5 control a       0.952       0    
6 control b       2.73        0
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is what you have in mind. You can actually use it for as many columns as possible. Here I created column names as the result of using `pivot_wider` in the form of `grp_gr2` so that I could change `grp` value from `ch1` for example to `control` corresponding with the desired `gr2` value. So with this name swapping we could get the value of our desired `control` group and use it in calculations.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dd %>%
  group_by(grp, gr2) %>%
  summarise(my_mean = mean(val)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = c(grp, gr2), values_from = my_mean, 
              names_glue = "{grp}_{gr2}") %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("ch"), ~ (.x - get(gsub("ch\\d", "control", cur_column()))) /
      get(gsub("ch\\d", "control", cur_column()))),
      across(starts_with("contro"), ~ .x - .x)) %>%
  pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = c("grp", "gr2"), values_to = "perc_val", 
               names_sep = "_")

# A tibble: 6 x 3
  grp     gr2   perc_val
  <chr>   <chr>    <dbl>
1 ch1     a        2.80 
2 ch1     b       -0.127
3 ch2     a        3.70 
4 ch2     b        0.345
5 control a        0    
6 control b        0
```